# Staying on same page after clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function "myfunction" applied on a submit button. The function shows a dialog box when the page is submitted and asks user if he is sure to submit the page?

The code of HTML button is:

```
<h:commandButton id="submit" value="Brewery 1" onclick="myfunction()" styleClass="button1">
<f:actionListener binding="#{loginweb.setNewUsernameAndCreateUser('Brewery1')}"/>
</h:commandButton>

**function myfunction(e)**
        {
         if(!confirm('Are you sure to proceed with this role?')) {
                e.preventDefault();
         }
        else {
         return false;
            }
        }
```

But when I press cancel (on appeared dialog box) the page is still submitted. What I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: onclick="myfunction(event)"

Comment: I think you need to apply the function and check `onSubmit` on `form` tag rather than `button` tag `onClick`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're passing the click event to `myfunction`. Try `onclick="myfunction(event)"`.